# Mac PHP compilation: Unrecognized options

Tags: apache-http-server, php, macos

I'm trying to compile PHP with a MSSQL extension.  I get this error:

`WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-php-config`

when I try to run `./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php5//bin/php-config` from the root of my PHP install folder.  The PATH is different than the norm because I installed PHP over CURL from this server in Switzerland called LIIP.

How do I address this error?

Comment: What does # ls /usr/local/php5//bin/php-config return?

Comment: /usr/local/php5/bin/php-config

Comment: Ignore the double /

Comment: No worries; the system won't care about double //, I just wanted to be sure you had a php-config file in the location.

Comment: It looks like I do.  Other suggestions?

Comment: open the `configure` file using text editor, and search for the option `--with-php-configure` , does it exist? is there any other option close enough to this one?

Comment: I'll try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I went dyslexic on you.

Here's a great article:

http://blog.benjaminwalters.net/?p=10

The gist is, why would you want to declare 'with-php' when you're compiling php?

G'luck!

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that; I've updated my answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.  That's similar to what I was doing, but thanks.